# Wrapping text around an image with indentation and justify

Tags: html, css

I want to make something like this.

The problem is that I need the `p` to have an indentation and justify as alignment.

I could float the image to the left and then set the display of `h3` and `p` to inline but then I am unable to set an indentation and more importantly to make the text justify.

[image]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}

p {
    text-align: justify;
    text-indent: 2em;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9VkQR/

Comment: I'm trying to tweak a CMS where I can't control the HTML structure. What I have is an opening P tag. The IMG is within the P and the actual content (text) follows the IMG tag. This results in the first line of text being next to the bottom of the image, not wrapped around it. If I use vertical-align:top on the IMG then one line of text appears next to the image before the rest drops down below. How to get multiple lines of text next to image, starting from top of image? I can apply CSS only - not change structure of HTML.

Comment: The problem with simply aligning it to the left is if it's taller than the paragraph, the image will spill out of the div. How do you prevent that?

Answer (score 3):

One more way to do the same. It can also use the [shape-outside](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside) property to control float text around an image.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 35rem;
}

h3 {
  line-height: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: -0.6rem;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
  text-indent: 2em;
}

img {
  width: 11rem;
  height: 11rem;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 2rem 1rem 0;
}

.shape {
  shape-outside: inset(0 0 0 0);
}

.circle {
  shape-outside: circle(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <img class='shape' src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
    alt="bulb">
  <h3>This is a heading</h3>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
    veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt
    in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<hr>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <img class='circle' src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
    alt="bulb">
  <h3>CSS Shape-Outside</h3>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
    veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt
    in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: how can I achieve your 2nd implementation with the image at the bottom-right corner?