# How to wrap text around an image using HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to design a block of text like the following picture:

[image]

Question whether this is possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrapping text around an image with indentation and justify](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209389/wrapping-text-around-an-image-with-indentation-and-justify)

Comment: Are you trying to wrap text around an image as in regular `<p>` tags and so on, but you also mentioned `<textarea>`, which could be a totally different problem.  Why don't you post your HTML if you have some? Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, you'd just float the php image to the left, and the text will wrap around it :-)

Answer (score 152):

you have to `float` your image container as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="floated">...some other random text</div>
    ...
    some random text
    ...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container{
    width: 400px;
    background: yellow;
}
#floated{
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    background: red;
}
```

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/kYDgL/

Answer (score 76):

With [CSS Shapes](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-shapes/) you can go one step further than just float text around a rectangular image.

You can actually wrap text such that it takes the shape of the edge of the image or polygon that you are wrapping it around.

### **[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zh4brvot/2/)** (Currently working on webkit - [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-shapes))

```css
.oval {
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  color: #111;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 90px;
  float: left;
  shape-outside: ellipse();
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: MediumPurple;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
span {
  padding-top: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="oval"><span>PHP</span>
</div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
  of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
  Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
  text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised
  in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

Also, here is a good [list apart article](http://alistapart.com/article/css-shapes-101) on CSS Shapes

Comment: Is there any option how to wrap "AROUND" the object so that the object can be in the middle?

Comment: @redestructa check out CSS exclusions.See my post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19895616/703717 It's currently only supported in IE - http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-exclusions

Answer (score 33):

*Addition to **BeNdErR**'s answer:*
 The "other TEXT" element should have `float:none`, like:

```html
    <div style="width:100%;">
        <div style="float:left;width:30%; background:red;">...something something something  random text</div>
        <div style="float:none; background:yellow;"> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: this is the only way I could get this to work.. And cleanest solution.

Comment: float:none was what saved me! Kept trying to float:right the second element to no avail.

Answer (score 14):

If the **image size is variable** or the design is **responsive**, in addition to wrapping the text, you can set a **min width for the paragraph** to avoid it to become too narrow.
Give an invisible CSS pseudo-element with the desired minimum paragraph width. If there isn't enough space to fit this pseudo-element, then it will be pushed down underneath the image, taking the paragraph with it.

```
#container:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: table;
  width: 10em;    /* Min width required */
}
#floated{
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: I think your answer may save me some bacon.  I was having a problem with  left floated images stacking up in a responsive design.  With my default image width being 30% and images on both sides, I could sometimes have a text column only 4 characters wide.

Answer (score 5):

## 2022 Update

I was trying to achieve this type of result with the least amount of code possible. This is what worked for me.

```css
#wrap {
    margin: 3em 8em;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.5em;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 1em;
}
p {
    margin-bottom: 2.5em;
    overflow: hidden; /* this is what keep the <p> from wrapping */
}
p:last-child {
    overflow: visible; /* this is an example of the browser default */
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<img class="left" src="http://dummyimage.com/172x172/0088cc/ffffff.gif&amp;text=.img">
<p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Donec id elit non
mi porta gravida at eget metus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac,
vestibulum at eros. Donec sed odio dui. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies
vehicula ut id elit. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus
dolor auctor. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec id
elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Praesent commodo cursus magna,
vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed
consectetur. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Morbi leo risus,
porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
<img
class="right" src="http://dummyimage.com/172x172/0088cc/ffffff.gif&amp;text=.img">
<p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Donec id elit non
mi porta gravida at eget metus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac,
vestibulum at eros. Donec sed odio dui. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies
vehicula ut id elit. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus
dolor auctor. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec id
elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Praesent commodo cursus magna,
vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed
consectetur. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Morbi leo risus,
porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
<img
class="right" src="http://dummyimage.com/172x172/0088cc/ffffff.gif&amp;text=.img">
<p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Donec id elit non
mi porta gravida at eget metus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac,
vestibulum at eros. Donec sed odio dui. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies
vehicula ut id elit. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus
dolor auctor. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec id
elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Praesent commodo cursus magna,
vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed
consectetur. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Morbi leo risus,
porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: man, just use a flexbox

Comment: @YuriyKravets : I personally find that flexbox is not very flexible in my honest opinion. The irony of the name. You cant maneuver around a flex.

Comment: @Grogu how can I place the 3rd `.img` at the bottom-right corner with the text still floated around it? I can't seem to achieve that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```css
        .my-image{
            width: -webkit-fill-available;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-left: 6px;
            padding-right: 6px;
        }
```

```html
    <div style="width:100%;">
        <div style="float: right;width: 40%;">
            <img class='my-image' src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952">
        </div>
        <div style="float:none; background:yellow;"> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  </div>
        <div style="float:none; background:green;"> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  </div>
        <div style="float:none; background:blue;"> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  </div>
        <div style="float:none; background:red;"> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  </div>
        <div style="float:none; background:green;"> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  </div>
        <div style="float:none; background:blue;"> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  </div>
        <div style="float:none; background:red;"> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  </div>
        <div style="float:none; background:green;"> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  </div>
        <div style="float:none; background:blue;"> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  </div>
        <div style="float:none; background:red;"> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  </div>
        <div style="float:none; background:green;"> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  </div>
        <div style="float:none; background:blue;"> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  </div>
    </div>
```