# Image inside text block

Tags: css, alignment, block

I am trying to code this block of text with image in it but for some reason it's not working for me as. What would be the best approach to get this right with CSS?
Thank you all!

**UPDATE**

This is what I got the problem is with that the underline heading 
http://jsfiddle.net/C2kqR/

```
.block h3{
    margin-bottom: 0.6em;
    margin-top: 0;
    color: #c80006;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;

}

.heading {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #c80006
}

.aleft {
    float:left; 
    margin:0 2em 0 0 !important;
}

.hr-line-full {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 22px 0 35px;
    display: block;
    border-top: 1px solid #dedede
}
```

Comment: Can you share the current code in jsfiddle for us to look at.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wrap text around an image using HTML/CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179424/how-to-wrap-text-around-an-image-using-html-css)

Comment: This is what I got so far http://jsfiddle.net/C2kqR/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a solution for you where you can remove the `hr` element you are trying to imitate and instead use `border` for the `h3`.

Changed CSS for `.heading`:

```
.heading {
    margin-bottom: 34px;
    padding-bottom: 24px;
    color: #c80006;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/aniketpant/5jw8F/)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T6sjt/)

CSS:

```
img{
    float:left;
    margin:0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

As long as the text and image are within a parent container, simply float the image left to have the text wrap around it. To Space it apart from the text, give it a margin and voila!

Comment: Thanks but my problem is that my underlined heading goes over the image. Is that possible to fix?