# Keep inline-block text next to image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place some text next to an image inside a container div of fixed width. To do this I'm using `display: inline-block` on the text. This works when the text is short but when it gets longer than the div it just moves downwards as seen in this snippet:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align: middle;
    
}

.text-container {
   margin-left: 10px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-e98D9RG3Gzs/U5XAgtaj9tI/AAAAAAAAIIo/hDPgyrWvxy0/s1600/shy-smiley.png"/>
  <div class="text-container">I AM TEXT</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-e98D9RG3Gzs/U5XAgtaj9tI/AAAAAAAAIIo/hDPgyrWvxy0/s1600/shy-smiley.png"/>
  <div class="text-container">I AM TEXT OH NOOO</div>
</div>
```

What I'd like to achieve is something like this:

[image: ideal]

So the text is still vertically aligned in the middle and next to the image.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `img` is an inline element, and the `.text-container` is an inline block. When the an inline element can't fit in the current line, the line breaks, and the element is moved to the next line.

To Prevent that set [`white-space: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) on the `.container`. To enable the wrap inside the `.text-container`, define it's width, and return the white space behavior to normal (wrap).

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  white-space: nowrap; /** force the elements to stay side by side **/
}

img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: middle
}

.text-container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 60px); /** containers width - img width - margin-left **/
  margin-left: 10px;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: middle
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-e98D9RG3Gzs/U5XAgtaj9tI/AAAAAAAAIIo/hDPgyrWvxy0/s1600/shy-smiley.png" />
  <div class="text-container">I AM TEXT</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-e98D9RG3Gzs/U5XAgtaj9tI/AAAAAAAAIIo/hDPgyrWvxy0/s1600/shy-smiley.png" />
  <div class="text-container">I AM TEXT OH NOOO</div>
</div>
```

However, you can simplify the structure even further by using a flexbox with `align-items: center`:

```css
.container {
  display: flex; /** set the container as flexbox **/
  align-items: center; /** align all items vertically **/
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.text-container {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-e98D9RG3Gzs/U5XAgtaj9tI/AAAAAAAAIIo/hDPgyrWvxy0/s1600/shy-smiley.png" />
  <div class="text-container">I AM TEXT</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-e98D9RG3Gzs/U5XAgtaj9tI/AAAAAAAAIIo/hDPgyrWvxy0/s1600/shy-smiley.png" />
  <div class="text-container">I AM TEXT OH NOOO</div>
</div>
```

And by using flexbox, you can also move the image with it's border to the background of `.container` to get a single div solution.

```css
.container {
  display: flex; /** set the container as flexbox **/
  align-items: center; /** align all items vertically **/
  box-sizing: border-box; /** the padding and the border are part of the width **/
  width: 202px;
  min-height: 54px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 60px; /** save space for the image and the margin between the image and the text **/
  border: 1px solid red;
  /** set the image and the image border as backgrounds **/
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, transparent 0, transparent 24px, black 24px, transparent 26px), url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-e98D9RG3Gzs/U5XAgtaj9tI/AAAAAAAAIIo/hDPgyrWvxy0/s1600/shy-smiley.png);
  /** set the backgrounds size **/
  background-size: 51px 51px, 50px 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /** prevent the backgrounds from repeating themselves to fill the container **/
  background-position: left center; /** position them in relation to the container **/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  I AM TEXT
</div>

<div class="container">
  I AM TEXT OH NOO
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to float the image, and use `display: block` on your `text-container`. That would wrap the text down below the image if it got big enough. I also moved the `margin` style to the image, and you could further adjust the spacing.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

img {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.text-container {
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-e98D9RG3Gzs/U5XAgtaj9tI/AAAAAAAAIIo/hDPgyrWvxy0/s1600/shy-smiley.png"/>
<div class="text-container">I AM TEXT OH NOOO</div>
</div>
```

Since everything is fixed size, you could also keep things as `inline-block`, but use a fixed `width` on your text container.

Answer (score 0):

CSS shapes [`shapeOutside:”rect()”`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26585749/11711280) & [`float:”left”`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19179519/11711280) on the image seems the way to go, lo, the css `calc()` in the container misses floated elements (edit: in the photo, I was using `ellipse()` instead. `height:"min-content"` on `<div></div>` parent needed when text outside isn't long enough for next photo, with text inside before or after your `<img/>`'s, using the parent as a group).  Staggering `float: "left"` or `"right"` looks nice but likely not best practice contenteditable as I originally suspected.)

[image: saverparty.xyz segment showing img element unaffected by container-css-calc]

Answer (score -1):

You are getting this because divs automatically put themselves on a newline. If you use the `<span>` tag around the text, it should show up on the same line as the image.

Try replacing:

```
<div class="text-container">I AM TEXT OH NOOO</div>
```

with:

```
<span class="text-container">I AM TEXT OH NOOO</span>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Only for highlighting effect with `backgroundColor`; CSS shapes `shapeOutside:”ellipse()”`& `float:”left”` on the image seems the way to go, lo, the `calc()` in the container misses floated elements