# Align text around an image floated to the right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get an image to appear in the top right corner of a div, with text first to the left of the image, and then when the image ends, the text should take up the full width of the div.

This is currently what is output:

[image]

This is the html:

```
<div>
<img src="./images/gym.jpeg" class="pic2"/>
slasdfkasjhdfkjasdhfkjlasdhfkjlashdfkjlshdKL
slasdfkasjhdfkjasdhfkjlasdhfkjlashdfkjlshdKL
slasdfkasjhdfkjasdhfkjlasdhfkjlashdfkjlshdKL
slasdfkasjhdfkjasdhfkjlasdhfkjlashdfkjlshdKL
slasdfkasjhdfkjasdhfkjlasdhfkjlashdfkjlshdKL
slasdfkasjhdfkjasdhfkjlasdhfkjlashdfkjlshdKL
slasdfkasjhdfkjasdhfkjlasdhfkjlashdfkjlshdKL
</div>
```

and this the css:

```
.description {
    padding: 0% 2% 1% 2%;
}

.description p {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.pic2 {
    float: right;
}
```

I have tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179424/how-to-wrap-text-around-an-image-using-html-css) however they have not worked for me, and give the same output as the image shown

Thanks for any help

Comment: Your markup works as-is. Can you reproduce the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/c8mabv5w/

Comment: Maybe you should use Lorem Ipsum text rather than absurdly long non-words for testing. :)

Comment: @isherwood So your solution would be to use shorter words? Yes, that would work as well. I assumed that the long words were there for a reason though...

Comment: I'd assume that the question would've mentioned it were that the case. Maybe not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to for the words to be breakable everywhere. So, `word-break: break-all;`

```css
.description {
  padding: 0% 2% 1% 2%;
}

.description p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.pic2 {
  float: right;
}

div {  /* new */
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/400x150" class="pic2" />  slasdfkasjhdfkjasdhfkjlasdhfkjlashdfkjlshdKL slasdfkasjhdfkjasdhfkjlasdhfkjlashdfkjlshdKL slasdfkasjhdfkjasdhfkjlasdhfkjlashdfkjlshdKL slasdfkasjhdfkjasdhfkjlasdhfkjlashdfkjlshdKL slasdfkasjhdfkjasdhfkjlasdhfkjlashdfkjlshdKL
slasdfkasjhdfkjasdhfkjlasdhfkjlashdfkjlshdKL slasdfkasjhdfkjasdhfkjlasdhfkjlashdfkjlshdKL
</div>
```

Comment: Is there anyway of doing this without having words overflow onto the next line?

Comment: changed it to ```word-break: break-word;```. Thanks

Comment: @wtreston Oh, but be careful, `word-break: break-word` doesn't work in all browsers. You can use `word-break: break-all; word-break: break-word;` for a fallback.