# How do I make an image span multiple columns while having text wrap around it?

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

I have a html element split into 3 columns using `column-count: 3;` I want to have an image span across two of the columns and have any text or other images wrap around it.

I know there are probably other ways to solve this without using `column-count` but I am programmatically creating the html so it is of variable length and content. `column-count` automatically handles

I tried changing the width of the image to `200%` but the text does not wrap around it.

This is my current formatting: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvmuZ.jpg

This is my desired formatting. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJM5j.jpg 
I want the image to be the size of the red rectangle with the text wrapping around it:

Here is the CSS I am using the achieve the desired result.

```
.blog-post {
    font-size: 8pt;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-family: Palatino;
    color: #414254;
        column-count: 3;
}

img {
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: This is not possible with CSS. You *can* span multiple columns using column-count but only ALL of the columns. If text is required to wrap around the image then there is no other method. - https://www.quackit.com/css/css3/properties/css_column-span.cfm

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding float to your css?

```
img {
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
}
```

OR you can try reading up more about it here:
[How to wrap text around an image using HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179424/how-to-wrap-text-around-an-image-using-html-css)