Text Wrap around JQuery Draggable/Resizable Image
I am trying to use JQuery, and want images to be resizable and draggable. I also want the text to wrap around the image (does not have to be real time) when the image is dragged or resized. Right now I can get the text to the side of the image, but once I add more text that the line breaks, it just moves the paragraph down under the image/container of the image.
I have already tried just setting a float to the containing div around the image, and the image itself. It sort of works but the text breaking is wrong. Maybe I am missing something extremely obvious.
EDIT: I made a mockup of what I need: Mockup. Let's say I have the following HTML:
<div id="draggable"><img id="resizable" src="..." alt="..." /></div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa
 voluptatem necessitatibus iure neque non, vero ipsum qui enim eius,
 aliquam et veniam mollitia hic! Perferendis?</p>

What JS/CSS systems do I need with JQuery/JQueryUI to get this to work as I want to?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not possible out of the box with Draggable or Resizable. The text will not flow around the elements as there is no collision. Since the text is contained within the Paragraph element, the draggable image would have to be part of the Paragraph. This would take a large amount of work overall. Also it would help if you provide a [mcve].

This is one place to begin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179424/how-to-wrap-text-around-an-image-using-html-css

So in the code base I have been working on, I completely forgot that I used &nbsp; to represent spaces to fix a different bug I had to deal with. Once changing how the spaces work, everything worked fine.
Why I needed &nbsp; is beyond me, and I am sure I will find new issues with the replacement code I have, but that is a problem for future me. I now have a class for spaces being 1ex, which is an idiotic fix but I now know &nbsp; !=  .
