# How to insert image wrapped by text in Xaringan slides

Tags: r-markdown, xaringan

I know in latex the code for inserting image wrapped by text is something like:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{img1.jpg}
    \caption{This is a figure positioned at the right and wrapped with text.}
    \label{fig:img1}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

I wonder if xaringan slide also has the same tools and if any how to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrapping text around an image with indentation and justify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209389/wrapping-text-around-an-image-with-indentation-and-justify)

Comment: You can simply use html (see above)